# Vk Developers Widgets

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я пытаюсь сделать виджет для своей группы:

```py
import vk_api

vk = vk_api.VkApi(token='My_token')

code = str({ 
            "title": "My Table", 
            "title_url": "https://vk.com/...", 
            "title_counter": 31, 
            "more": "Посмотреть все результаты", 
            "more_url": "https://vk.com/...", 
            "head": [{ 
                      "text": "Название первой колонки" 
                     }, { 
                      "text": "Название второй колонки", 
                      "align": "center" 
                    }], 
            "body": [ 
                    [{ 
                      "text": "Это первая ячейка первой строки", 
                      "icon_id": "3484735_..." 
                     }, 
                     { 
                       "text": "Это вторая ячейка первой строки", 
                       "url": "https://vk.com/..." 
                     }], 
                     [{ 
                       "text": "Это первая ячейка второй строки", 
                       "icon_id": "3484735_..." 
                      }, 
                      { 
                       "text": "Это вторая ячейка второй строки", 
                       "url": "https://vk.com/..." 
                      } 
                     ] 
                    ] 
            })

vk.method('appWidgets.update',
                 {'code': code,
                  'type': 'table'})
```

Но у меня появляется ошибка:

```
vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [12] Unable to compile code: ';' expected, ' in line 1
```

Подскажите в чем ошибка?

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `str(...)` воспользоваться `json.dumps(..., ensure_ascii=False)`.

Comment: И в параметре `code` ожидается какой-то `VKScript`, возвращающий `json`, а не просто `json`. Из [документации](https://vk.com/dev/apps_widgets?f=1.%20%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0): *code (string) — код виджета. Аналог параметра code в методе execute. ... code должен возвращать JSON-объект, описывающий виджет. ...*.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов Я попробовал вместо str(...) использовать json.dumps(..., ensure_ascii=False), но всё равно происходит такая же ошибка(